# error 13 type mismatch copy paste

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, where I changed some values. Now I have the following error: error 13, type do not match. The error is pointing is this direction:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AS").Range("A10:M19").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("InvoerIO").Range("A1:M10").Offset(z, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the value of `z`.
I have tried to following, it works:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Worksheets(1).Range("A10:M19").Copy
    Worksheets(2).Range("A1:M10").Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: No it doesnt work. (forgot some **s** somewhere**s**. :D

Comment: @A.S.H I added Worksheet(1) later, initially it was with the original names of my Excel :D

Comment: Thank you! Indeed that was the problem. z was a string instead of an integer.

Comment: @Johan the take-away is "declare all your variables with an explicit type, and use meaningful names". `z` doesn't mean anything. Also FWIW you don't want to use an `Integer` for anything that means to represent a row number. Use a `Long` instead, lest you run into overflow errors one day or another.